# Error scraper Facebook posts: JSON to csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I made this example code from the package facebook_scraper. It has already been created by someone else, but I just used it. The scraper works (when I print the json.dumps), but it gives me an error when writing the json to csv. Can someone help please? I just want it to be easily viewable in csv.

The error and code are shown below:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-6ca88d5c5b11> in <module>
     29 with open('dataset1.csv', 'a') as csv_dataset:
     30     for scrape in scraped_pages:
---> 31         a = pd.read_json(json.dumps(scrape.__dict__), csv_dataset)
     32         csv_dataset.write(a.to_csv() + '\n')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    197                 else:
    198                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 199             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    200 
    201         return cast(F, wrapper)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_json.py in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit, encoding, lines, chunksize, compression, nrows)
    591 
    592     compression = infer_compression(path_or_buf, compression)
--> 593     filepath_or_buffer, _, compression, should_close = get_filepath_or_buffer(
    594         path_or_buf, encoding=encoding, compression=compression
    595     )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_filepath_or_buffer(filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression, mode, storage_options)
    219 
    220         try:
--> 221             file_obj = fsspec.open(
    222                 filepath_or_buffer, mode=mode or "rb", **(storage_options or {})
    223             ).open()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py in open(urlpath, mode, compression, encoding, errors, protocol, newline, **kwargs)
    427     ``OpenFile`` object.
    428     """
--> 429     return open_files(
    430         [urlpath],
    431         mode,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py in open_files(urlpath, mode, compression, encoding, errors, name_function, num, protocol, newline, auto_mkdir, expand, **kwargs)
    278     be used as a single context
    279     """
--> 280     fs, fs_token, paths = get_fs_token_paths(
    281         urlpath,
    282         mode,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/core.py in get_fs_token_paths(urlpath, mode, num, name_function, storage_options, protocol, expand)
    598                     "share the same protocol"
    599                 )
--> 600         cls = get_filesystem_class(protocol)
    601         optionss = list(map(cls._get_kwargs_from_urls, urlpath))
    602         paths = [cls._strip_protocol(u) for u in urlpath]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fsspec/registry.py in get_filesystem_class(protocol)
    189     if protocol not in registry:
    190         if protocol not in known_implementations:
--> 191             raise ValueError("Protocol not known: %s" % protocol)
    192         bit = known_implementations[protocol]
    193         try:

ValueError: Protocol not known: {"url": "https
```

> 

```
import facebook_scraper
import json
import pandas as pd
 
page_to_scrape = 'ikea'
number_of_pages = 1
 
 
class FacebookScrape:
    def __init__(self, url, content, time, likes, shares, comments):
        self.url = url
        self.content = content
        self.time = time
        self.likes = likes
        self.shares = shares
        self.comments = comments
 
scraped_pages = []

for post in facebook_scraper.get_posts(page_to_scrape, pages=number_of_pages, options={'reactors': True}):
    scraped_url = post['post_url']
    scraped_content = post['text']
    scraped_time = post['time']
    scraped_likes = post['likes']
    scraped_shares = post['shares']
    scraped_comments = post['comments']
    scraped_pages.append(FacebookScrape(scraped_url, scraped_content, str(scraped_time), scraped_likes, scraped_shares, scraped_comments))
    
with open('dataset1.csv', 'a') as csv_dataset:
    for scrape in scraped_pages:
        a = pd.read_json(json.dumps(scrape.__dict__))
        csv_dataset.write(a.to_csv() + '\n')
```